# Why Python ignores the sign in the column name?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe of text that looks like this

```
RepID, Txt
1, +83 -193 -380 +55 +901
2, -94 +44 +2892 -60
3, +7010 -3840 +3993
```

Although the Txt field have +282 and -829 but these are string values not numeric

The problem is that when I use Bag of words function

```
def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
  cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(), columns=CountVec.get_feature_names_out(), index=df.index)  # <- HERE
  return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)
```

I get the result columns without any sign + or -

the outcome is

```
RepID 83 193 380 55 ...
1     1  1   1   1
2     0  0   0   0
```

it should be

```
RepID +83 -193 -380 +55 ...
1     1   1    1    1
2     0   0    0    0
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import ..... ## import other stuffs


def custom_tokenizer(text):
    tokens = [token.strip() for token in re.split('([+-]?\d+)', text) if token.strip()] # Splitinput text into tokens taking into account numeric values and signs both
    return tokens

def BOW(df):
    CountVec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=custom_tokenizer)
    Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df['Txt'])
    Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
    cv_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(), columns=CountVec.get_feature_names_out(), index=df.index)
    return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)

### Test the Bow() func
data = {'RepID': [1, 2, 3],
        'Txt': ['+83 -193 -380 +55 +901', '-94 +44 +2892 -60', '+7010 -3840 +3993']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = BOW(df)
print(result)
```

The issue you are seeing is because of the way the CountVectorizer is tokenizing the input. By default, CountVectorizer uses a regx to tokenize the input and it considers only alphanumeric characters as tokens. Therefore "+" and "-" signs are being excluded during tokenization.

In the above code I am using custom tokenizer that considers both numeric values and the signs.

Answer (score 0):

After a slight modification to the `BOW` function I was able to replicate your issue. What I found is that the [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) is using the analyzer option "word" which ignores non-word characters. If you change the analyzer you can make it perform however you want. In this case, I simply split the string, though you can perform more complex operations if you have more data not shown here which requires it.

Here is some minimally altered example code that produces your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


def BOW(df):
    CountVec = CountVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x.split()) # <-
    Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(list(df['Txt']))
    Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
    cv_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
        Count_data.toarray(),
        columns=CountVec.get_feature_names_out(),
        index=df.index
    )
    return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)


a = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'RepId': 1, 'Txt': '+83 -193 -380 +55 +901'},
    {'RepId': 2, 'Txt': '-94 +44 +2892 -60'},
    {'RepId': 3, 'Txt': '+7010 -3840 +3993'}
])

b = BOW(a)
print(b)
```

And here is what it produced for me which closes matches your desired output:

```
   +2892  +3993  +44  +55  +7010  +83  +901  -193  -380  -3840  -60  -94
0      0      0    0    1      0    1     1     1     1      0    0    0
1      1      0    1    0      0    0     0     0     0      0    1    1
2      0      1    0    0      1    0     0     0     0      1    0    0
```

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to Aswin answer, you can directly pass the regex to the CountVectorizer object:

```
CountVec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'([+-]?\d+)')
```